# variables overflow despite modulus c

Tags: c

> this source code is suppossed to solve a problem using matrix
> exponentiation,even though i used a struct called state because it
> helps me understand what im doing.(The problem is called Unlucky 13
> hackerearth),so this works like a charm for t=1(t->test cases) n =
> [2,9] **but for         n=10 it overflows and gives negative
> numbers** [output that shows values that overflowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95d0n.png)

```c
    
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    typedef struct {
        int HH, HS;
        int SH, SS;
    } State;
    
    void set(State* f, int hh, int hs, int sh, int ss) {
        f->HH = hh;
        f->HS = hs;
        f->SH = sh;
        f->SS = ss;
    }
    void printState(State state) {
        printf("HH %d\n", state.HH);
        printf("HS %d\n", state.HS);
        printf("SH %d\n", state.SH);
        printf("SS %d\n", state.SS);
    }
    int solution(State f) {
        return (f.HH + f.HS) % 1000000009;
    }
    State multiply(State x, State y) {
        State product;
        product.HH = (x.HH) * (y.HH) + (x.HS) * (y.SH);
        product.HS = (x.HS) * (y.SS) + (x.HH) * (y.HS);
        product.SH = (x.SH) * (y.HH) + (x.SS) * (y.SH);
        product.SS = (x.SS) * (y.SS) + (x.SH) * (y.HS);
        return product;
    }
    // binary exponentation
    State power(State base, int exponent) {
        State result;
        if(exponent == 0) {
            set(&result, 1, 0, 0, 1); // if it get multiplied by matrix return same matrix
            return result;
        } else if(exponent % 2 == 1) {
            result = multiply(power(base, exponent - 1), base);
            return result;
        } else {
            result = power(base, exponent / 2);
            return multiply(result, result);
        }
    }
    int main() {
        int t;
        scanf("%d", &t);
        while(t < 1 || t > 100001) {
            scanf("%d", &t);
        }
        int n;
        for(int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &n);
            while(n < 1 || n > 1000000010) {
                scanf("%d", &n);
            }
            State state;
            set(&state, 9, 1, 8, 1);
            state = power(state, n);
            printf("\n");
    
            State one;
            set(&one, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            printf("%d", solution(state));
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

output

> 1              //input
> 10             //input
> //output
> result: 537716907
> HH -384363143
> HS 922080050
> SH -213294183
> SS 828931049
>
> correct output was 127651418 (for input 1 10)
> as tstanisl pointed out
> Ι modified the multiply function (cast long long and modulo)

```c
State multiply(State x,State y){
    State product;
    product.HH = ((long long)x.HH * y.HH + (long long)x.HS * y.SH) % 1000000009;
    product.HS = ((long long)x.HS * y.SS + (long long)x.HH * y.HS) % 1000000009;
    product.SH = ((long long)x.SH * y.HH + (long long)x.SS * y.SH) % 1000000009;
    product.SS = ((long long)x.SS * y.SS + (long long)x.SH * y.HS) % 1000000009;
    return product;
    
}
```

thanks for your time in advance

Comment: You cannot just do the modulo at the end. You need to ensure no intermediate calculations overflow.

Comment: If that does not solve your problem, edit the question to provide a [mre]. Do not post the input and output as an image; paste them as text. (Use the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags to mark it as preformatted text.) Show the same code in the question as the code that produced the output. (The output in the image shows output labeled “HH”, “HS”, “SH”, and “SS” that is not produced by the code in the question. Always match exactly the code and the output you show.) Say what the correct output for “result” is or say how you know it is wrong or how we can know when it is right.

Comment: The C `%` operator is not a true modulus operator.  It's a remainder operator.  On most systems, `-1 / 2` truncates to zero, in which case `-1 % 2` is `-1`, not `1`.  So if your values ever overflow to negative values, they will most likely remain negative.  Plus there's no guarantee that overflowed values will even retain the desired low-order bits.

Comment: eric it is the printState function that shows the structs variables and the other output is the solution function (1 and 10 are the input)

Comment: so I have to create a modulus function dont I?So that it turns negative values to possitive , possibly if i have -9999mod x i wiil add x to -9999 until it gets to >0 and <x, I will go do that

Comment: oh yeah low-order bits :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the program has to efficiently compute n-th power of 2x2 matrix with scalar in "Z mod 1000000009" ring.

As it was mentioned in the comments you must ensure that result of every operation must be mapped to the ring.

The interesting part is 4 lines in `multiply()`:

```
product.HH = (x.HH) * (y.HH) + (x.HS) * (y.SH);
```

Multiplying two `int`s from 0-1000000008 range will likely overflow 32-bit long `int` producing something that is a binary representation of a *negative* int.

Try to make operation using a longer integer type (i.e. `long long`) to ensure no overflow in the operation. Finally, map the result back to the ring with `%` operator.

```
product.HH = ((long long)x.HH * y.HH + (long long)x.HS * y.SH) % 1000000009;
```

The final function would be:

```
    State multiply(State x, State y) {
        State product;
        product.HH = ((long long)x.HH * y.HH + (long long)x.HS * y.SH) % 1000000009;
        product.HS = ((long long)x.HS * y.SS + (long long)x.HH * y.HS) % 1000000009;
        product.SH = ((long long)x.SH * y.HH + (long long)x.SS * y.SH) % 1000000009;
        product.SS = ((long long)x.SS * y.SS + (long long)x.SH * y.HS) % 1000000009;
        return product;
    }
```

The printed result is:

```
127651418
HH 205571377
HS 922080050
SH 376640337
SS 828931049
```

Answer (score 0):

for this type of usage (when your variable can't be negative) you can use unsigned int, with it the max value of int or other numerical type.

otherwise if an int is not suffisant for you you can use long, or long long, to see what are the max size of each one you can refer to google or <limit.h>

Comment: Better to use the types in stdint.h, then you know what sizes you get.